# How to kill a process except one?

Tags: linux, kill-process

I have few processes starting with string apple. So my processes names are apple1, apple2, apple3 till apple10. Now I use command "pkill -f apple". But it kills all processes starting with apple. I want apple2 not to get killed with the above command. So can someone tell me how the above command can be modified?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: is there a reason you can't just kill them individually?

Comment: No I can't kill them individually for some valid reason that I have not mentioned to keep the question short

Answer (score 2):

This works for excluding the apple2 pid from the list and kill others , Not sure if your problem will be solved with this.

```
ps -aef | grep apple | grep -v apple2 | awk '{print $2}'|while read pid
do
kill -9 $pid
done
```